# Put Ubuntu NetworkManager back on notification bar

Tags: linux, networkmanager, gnome3

I am running the GNOME 3 desktop environment on Ubuntu 11.04. I accidentally clicked the "Don't show again" option when a notification from NetworkManager came up, but would now like to have it back. How can I restore it?

Answer (score 1):

**Restore a missing network manager.**

Run application (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or click on empty space on panel scroll to 'run application' add to panel.

1. Press the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. This opens the "Run Application" window.
2. Type into the "Run Application" text box:

   ```
   nm-applet --sm-disable
   ```
3. Click "Run"

   [image: Snip of Run App on vbox,ubuntu]

Read [this article](http://practicalswitchtoubuntu.blogspot.com/2009/02/restore-missing-network-manager-applet.html) for more information.

Open terminal and type `gconf-editor` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
This will open the 'Configuration Editor'.

After that, go to:

1. `/apps/nm-applets`

   Click on it. Clicking on the right side will tell you what each file does.
2. `/schemas/apps/nm-applets`

[image: image of ubuntu config editor]

Your NetManager could be set to 'hide'. I do not know which box to tick to restore. It could be 'disable-disconnected-notifications'.